# Amazon S3 Policy for only PUT,Read and List

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I'm trying to create a policy for only read/put/list my bucket and a dir into it.
I've write this policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2014-05-19",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [ "s3:Put*", "s3:Get*" ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<mybucket>/<mydirectoryinbucket>/*"
        }
    ]
}

{
    "Version": "2014-05-19",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Condition": { "StringLike": { "s3:prefix": "<mydirectoryinbucket>/*"} },
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<mybucket>"
        }
    ]
}
```

But I get error on the last line of the first policy...the error is only syntax error, and no additional informations.

Where I did wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You're at the very least missing the [principal](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/AccessPolicyLanguage_ElementDescriptions.html#Principal), which defines the entity that is allowed or denied access to a resource.

I took your policy, added the wildcard * to denote 'any' principal, and regenerated it with the [IAM Policy Generator](http://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html). Try this:

```
{
  "Id": "Policy1432045314996",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "PublicGetAndPutPolicy",
      "Action": [
        "s3:Get*",
        "s3:Put*"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<mybucket>/<mydirectoryinbucket>/*",
      "Principal": "*"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "PublicListPolicy",
      "Action": [
        "s3:ListBucket"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<mybucket>",
      "Condition": {
        "StringLike": {
          "s3:prefix": "<mydirectoryinbucket>/*"
        }
      },
      "Principal": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Documentation:

- [Specifying a Principal in a Policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/s3-bucket-user-policy-specifying-principal-intro.html)